# How to add a request header in Bayeux Client Request?

Tags: cometd, bayeux

I am using the Bayeux Java Client, and I am trying to add a request header for all the 
requests made to the server, including the handshake request.

Currently I am using :

```
   mTransport = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient) {
        @Override
        protected void customize(ContentExchange exchange) {
            super.customize(exchange);
            if (mCrumb != null) {
                exchange.addRequestHeader("Header Key", "Header value");
            }
        }
    };

    mClient = new BayeuxClient(HANDSHAKE_URL, mTransport);
```

Is this the right way? I am not able to get it to work? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the right way to do it.

In the [CometD](http://cometd.org) test suite there is a [test](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/2.8.x/cometd-java/cometd-java-client/src/test/java/org/cometd/client/HandshakeWithAuthenticationTest.java) that performs what you are doing.